# Accessing Variable in JS file - laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel

I don't know if this question is valid for stack overflow. But i have a controller which returns my home page which displays a chart(pie-chart).

There is a JS file in the public folder which supports the display of the chart and its data.

I want to insert $setData into the JS file to replace the data for `Red` in the JS file below..

When i insert `$setData`, i get an error and the chart doesn't show up.

The JS file is already imported into the Home blade folder.

How do i do this?

**Controller**

```
  public function home(Request $request) 
  {

     $setData = Set::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->orderBy('created_at','DESC')->first();
     return view('home', compact('setData'));
  }
```

**Home**

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                  <a class="heading-elements-toggle"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v font-medium-3"></i></a>
                  <div class="heading-elements">
                    <ul class="list-inline mb-0">
                      <!-- <li><a data-action="collapse"><i class="ft-minus"></i></a></li> -->
                      <li><a  title="reload"  data-action="reload"><i class="ft-rotate-cw"></i></a></li>
                      <li><a data-action="expand" title="expand" ><i class="ft-maximize"></i></a></li>
                      <!-- <li><a data-action="close"><i class="ft-x"></i></a></li> -->
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

**app/asset/js File**

```
    <script>
$(window).on("load", function(){

    //Get the context of the Chart canvas element we want to select
    var ctx = $("#simple-pie-chart");

    // Chart Options
    var chartOptions = {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        responsiveAnimationDuration:500,
    };

    // Chart Data
    var chartData = {
        labels: ["Red", "Yellow", "Blue"],
        datasets: [{
            label: "My First dataset",
            data: [85, 65, 34],
            backgroundColor: ['#00A5A8', '#626E82', '#FF7D4D','#FF4558', '#16D39A'],
        }]
    };

    var config = {
        type: 'pie',

        // Chart Options
        options : chartOptions,

        data : chartData
    };

    // Create the chart
    var pieSimpleChart = new Chart(ctx, config);
});
        </script>
```

Comment: What error do you get

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz  the pie chart doesn't appear..not a specific error. Is there a way i can insert `setData` from the controller into the JS file

Comment: Go to the console. That should throw some kind of error

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz, `setData is not defined`

Comment: Sure it is. You just need to create a new variable containing your server data. `var setData = {!! json_encode($setData) !!}`

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz In the js folder? I am getting syntax error

Comment: In your blade file. Laravel syntax always goes in the `.blade.php` file

Comment: Worked..Thank you